Show state or province labels in the centre of a Google Maps JavaScript API custom styled map
We're using the Google Maps JavaScript API with a custom styled map (Google Maps Studio) and want to show the label in the centre of the shape for "state or province" in South Africa. I can see it shows for states in the USA and Canada but not for other countries. If you zoom in enough the "state or province" label does show up on either side of the border of the "state or province" but we want it to show at different zoom levels and in the centre of the shape. I tried to upload a new dataset of South African provinces as a centre point latitude and longitude but it just shows a white circle and not the province name. Also there is no Google Maps Studio styling options for the custom dataset.
